# Fill in missing dates in SQL Table and take last market value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, row

I have the following Table

```
Account Netflow FeeAmount   Income  TWR MarketValue Date
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    375645.74   3/31/2004
33L951572   5547.31 0.00    0.00    0.08    338817.64   12/31/2004
33L951572   13250.45    0.00    35.00   0.01    322791.22   12/31/2005
33L951572   344.12  0.00    310.66  0.02    328899.02   1/31/2006
33L951572   6168.03 0.00    69.78   0.03    326221.04   2/28/2006
33L951572   140.50  0.00    186.62  0.01    328616.53   3/31/2006
```

I need this table to have a row for every month end and the date is always a month end date. However there are gaps in the dates. You can see for example 3/31/2004 jumps to 12/31/2014 then 12/31/2014 jumps to 12/31/2015, after which the data is monthly.

I want to insert a row with 0's in all rows. However I would also like to include the last known MarketValue whatever it may be before the gap.

So ideally this table would look as follows.

```
Account Netflow FeeAmount   Income  TWR MarketValue Date
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  3/31/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  4/30/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  5/31/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  6/30/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  7/31/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  8/31/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  9/30/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  10/31/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   375,645.74  11/30/2004
33L951572   5,547.31    0.00    0.00    0.077   338,817.64  12/31/2004
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  1/31/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  2/28/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  3/31/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  4/30/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  5/31/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  6/30/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  7/31/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  8/31/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  9/30/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  10/31/2005
33L951572   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   338,817.64  11/30/2005
33L951572   13,250.45   0.00    35.00   0.006   322,791.22  12/31/2005
33L951572   344.12  0.00    310.66  0.019   328,899.02  1/31/2006
33L951572   6,168.03    0.00    69.78   0.026   326,221.04  2/28/2006
33L951572   140.50  0.00    186.62  0.007   328,616.53  3/31/2006
```

**The query provided below by Clockwork Muse works perfectly if there is only one attribute to perform the logic on. That attribute in the first example is Account.**

**However I've realized some of my data needs to be partitioned by a second criteria, AssetClassCode. Meaning within accounts there are sub attributes. Here is the example again but with the added attribute.**

```
Account Netflow FeeAmount   Income  TWR AssetClassCode  AssetClass  MarketValue Date
33L951572   0   5   0   0.87947 1   Cash    1000    3/31/2004
33L951572   0   6   45  0.25564 2   Equity  2000    3/31/2004
33L951572   0   8   5   0.90677 3   Fixed   3000    3/31/2004
33L951572   123 5   2   0.29787 1   Cash    4000    7/30/2014
33L951572   456 4   4   0.55341 2   Equity  5000    7/30/2014
33L951572   657 2   45  0.10634 3   Fixed   6000    7/30/2014
```

Here is the desired result

```
Account Netflow FeeAmount   Income  TWR AssetClassCode  AssetClass   MarketValue    Date
    33L951572   0   5   0   0.88    1   Cash    1000    3/31/2004
    33L951572   0   6   45  0.26    2   Equity  2000    3/31/2004
    33L951572   0   8   5   0.91    3   Fixed   3000    3/31/2004
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    1   Cash    1000    4/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    2   Equity  2000    4/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    3   Fixed   3000    4/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    1   Cash    1000    5/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    2   Equity  2000    5/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    3   Fixed   3000    5/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    1   Cash    1000    6/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    2   Equity  2000    6/30/2014
    33L951572   0   0   0   0.00    3   Fixed   3000    6/30/2014
    33L951572   123 5   2   0.30    1   Cash    4000    7/30/2014
    33L951572   456 4   4   0.55    2   Equity  5000    7/30/2014
    33L951572   657 2   45  0.11    3   Fixed   6000    7/30/2014
```

**UPDATE**

I'm getting redundant values. I made a new table called CAC_Codes that reflects what you have in AssetClass. The relevant tables are now FTDatelist as the calendar table. FTPerfCACCAssetClass which has the various measures, and CAC_Codes which has the asset clsas information.

```
SELECT Account.accountID, 
       COALESCE(FTPerfCACCAssetClass.AccountNetDeposits, 0) AS netFlow, COALESCE(FTPerfCACCAssetClass.AccountFees, 0) AS feeAmount, 
       COALESCE(FTPerfCACCAssetClass.AccountIncome, 0) AS income, COALESCE(FTPerfCACCAssetClass.AccountReturn, 0) AS TWR,
       CAC_Codes.assetClassCode, CAC_Codes.assetClass,
       MarketValue.AccountMKV,
       Calendar.calendarDate
FROM (SELECT MAX(calendarDate) AS calendarDate
      FROM FTDateList
      GROUP BY calendarYear, calendarMonth) Calendar
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT accountID
            FROM FTPerfCACCAssetClass) Account
CROSS JOIN CAC_Codes
LEFT JOIN FTPerfCACCAssetClass
       ON FTPerfCACCAssetClass.accountID = Account.accountID
          AND FTPerfCACCAssetClass.assetClassCode = CAC_Codes.assetClassCode
          AND FTPerfCACCAssetClass.EndDate = Calendar.calendarDate
JOIN (SELECT accountid, assetClassCode,
             AccountMKV,
             EndDate AS valueStartDate,
             LEAD(EndDate, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, EndDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY accountid, assetClassCode ORDER BY EndDate) AS valueEndDate
              FROM FTPerfCACCAssetClass) MarketValue
  ON MarketValue.accountID = Account.accountID
     AND MarketValue.assetClassCode = CAC_Codes.assetClassCode
     AND Calendar.calendarDate >= MarketValue.valueStartDate
     AND Calendar.calendarDate < MarketValue.valueEndDate
ORDER BY Account.accountID, Calendar.calendarDate, CAC_Codes.assetClassCode
```

However I'm getting results that look like this.

```
accountID   netFlow feeAmount   income  TWR assetClassCode  assetClass  AccountMKV  calendarDate
100106  11532813.47000000000    0.00000000000   0.00000000000   0.00000000000   36  Domestic Large Cap  11532813.48000000000    2007-03-31
100106  11532813.47000000000    0.00000000000   0.00000000000   0.00000000000   36  Domestic Large Cap  11532813.48000000000    2007-03-31
100106  11532813.47000000000    0.00000000000   0.00000000000   0.00000000000   36  Domestic Large Cap  11532813.48000000000    2007-03-31
100106  11532813.47000000000    0.00000000000   0.00000000000   0.00000000000   36  Domestic Large Cap  11532813.48000000000    2007-03-31
100106  3055.94000000000    0.00000000000   1.38000000000   -0.06492600000  1   Cash and Money Market   2857.53000000000    2007-04-30
100106  3055.94000000000    0.00000000000   1.38000000000   -0.06492600000  1   Cash and Money Market   2857.53000000000    2007-04-30
100106  3055.94000000000    0.00000000000   1.38000000000   -0.06492600000  1   Cash and Money Market   2857.53000000000    2007-04-30
100106  3055.94000000000    0.00000000000   1.38000000000   -0.06492600000  1   Cash and Money Market   2857.53000000000    2007-04-30
```

Comment: What have you got so far?  Why modify the table, instead of creating a view with this information?  As James's answer mentions, a calendar table would be helpful here, do you have one. (Even without using it for this query, calendar tables are probably **the** most useful analysis table you can have, especially indexed to the gills)

Comment: I made a date table and tried to join to it, but I get a bunch of columns with all nulls. I need to do a cross join or some type of interpolation where I am getting the missing date but it includes all other rows of relevant data like account, netflow, feeamount etc.. I'd like to pull the last marketvalue but I can figure that out later, for now I just want to fill in the date gaps. I followed the link and tried the suggesitons but I can't translate it into my specific need.

Comment: Side note: there are 31 days in July (month 7), so that better not be what you're expecting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big problem is that you actually want two *different* things on each date:

1. The "instant" value of the row (fee, income, etc).
2. The *ongoing* value of a column (market value).

Now that we know what we're looking for, we can construct our statement.

First, I'm going to assume that you have both a calendar table and an account table (or would be only interested in one account, and don't need the extra join).  We'll need to deal with the calendar data a bit, but accounts should be fine as-is.  These form the initial basis of the query:

```
SELECT Account.account, 
       -- instantaneous columns
       -- ongoing columns
       Calendar.calendarDate
FROM (SELECT MAX(calendarDate) AS calendarDate
      FROM Calendar
      GROUP BY calendarYear, calendarMonth) Calendar
CROSS JOIN Account
```

This gives us a list of all accounts with all dates.  You can add restrictions as necessary - you probably have dates in the future, after all - but the important part is getting the max date of each month.  (Personally, I probably would have gone for the **first** day of the month because it's far easier to index that, but this works)  The resulting Calendar query table is likely to be pulled into memory - it's **very** small (12 rows a year!).

Next comes getting the "instantaneous" row.  Now that we have our "base" data, a simple join suffices:

```
COALESCE(MarketData.netFlow, 0) AS netFlow, COALESCE(MarketData.feeAmount, 0) AS feeAmount, 
COALESCE(MarketData.income, 0) AS income, COALESCE(MarketData.TWR, 0) AS TWR, 
......
LEFT JOIN MarketData
       ON MarketData.marketDate = Calendar.calendarDate
          AND MarketData.account = Account.account
```

... so *if* we have a row there, then display it.  When we don't have a row, the value is `0`.

And lastly, we need the "ongoing" value.  This we have to collect separately.  Now, normally you want to use something like `LAG(marketValue)`... unfortunately, the join to our "base" tables gives us a bunch of rows where `marketValue` is *null*, so the windowing would return that instead of our "previous" value.  We need to create a range-query table.
A range query table is where you have an upper and lower bound for a given key.  In the case of dates (like all positive-range key values), this is lower-bound inclusive (`>=`) and upper-bound exclusive (`<`).  Essentially, our upper-bound here is the first instant we have a **new** market value (the old one is superseded).  *This* we can use `LEAD(...)` to get:

```
MarketValue.marketValue,
........
JOIN (SELECT account, marketValue,
             marketDate AS valueStartDate,
             LEAD(marketDate, 1, '99991231') OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY marketDate) AS valueEndDate
      FROM MarketData) MarketValue
  ON Calendar.calendarDate >= MarketValue.valueStartDate
     AND Calendar.calendarDate < MarketValue.valueEndDate
     AND MarketValue.Account = Account.account
```

Our `MarketValue` inline query returns a table that looks something like this:

> 33L951572 | 375645.74 | 2004-03-31 | 2004-12-31

... that we can join to for each row.  Note how the join condition is constructed - this makes it so that there isn't a conflict between "old" and "new" `marketValue`s.  On the last row, because `LEAD(...)` would return a null value, we return the "next" day; because (again) we use an exclusive upper-bound, this makes our last entry the last joinable row.

Putting it all together gives this:

```
SELECT Account.account, 
       COALESCE(MarketData.netFlow, 0) AS netFlow, COALESCE(MarketData.feeAmount, 0) AS feeAmount, 
       COALESCE(MarketData.income, 0) AS income, COALESCE(MarketData.TWR, 0) AS TWR,            
       MarketValue.marketValue,
       Calendar.calendarDate
FROM (SELECT MAX(calendarDate) AS calendarDate
      FROM Calendar
      GROUP BY calendarYear, calendarMonth) Calendar
CROSS JOIN Account
LEFT JOIN MarketData
       ON MarketData.marketDate = Calendar.calendarDate
          AND MarketData.account = Account.account   
JOIN (SELECT account, marketValue,
             marketDate AS valueStartDate,
             LEAD(marketDate, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, marketDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY marketDate) AS valueEndDate
      FROM MarketData) MarketValue
  ON Calendar.calendarDate >= MarketValue.valueStartDate
     AND Calendar.calendarDate < MarketValue.valueEndDate
     AND MarketValue.Account = Account.account
ORDER BY Account.account, Calendar.calendarDate
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/083ae/22/0)</kbd>

(don't forget the outer `ORDER BY`, or rows may appear where you least expect them!)

---

### Modifying the query

For each additional criteria to partition, or "repeat" by, there are a few simple steps to take.

First, you need to add the "base" reference, to ensure all rows are present:

```
-- I'm assuming you have a code reference table.  
-- Otherwise, create it like I did for the account table
CROSS JOIN AssetClass
```

- Step 1b - use this base reference for the columns in the `SELECT`, and probably the `ORDER BY` as well.

Second, you need to add the extra key value to both "child" table join conditions:

```
-- Because asset-class - 'Cash', etc - are _dependent_ values,
-- we only need the code key in this case
AND MarketData.assetClassCode = AssetClass.assetClassCode
```

Lastly, you need to add the relevant column to the partitioning:

... OVER (PARTITION BY account, assetClassCode ORDER BY marketDate) ...

Resulting in:

```
SELECT Account.account, 
       COALESCE(MarketData.netFlow, 0) AS netFlow, COALESCE(MarketData.feeAmount, 0) AS feeAmount, 
       COALESCE(MarketData.income, 0) AS income, COALESCE(MarketData.TWR, 0) AS TWR,
       AssetClass.assetClassCode, AssetClass.assetClass,            
       MarketValue.marketValue,
       Calendar.calendarDate
FROM (SELECT MAX(calendarDate) AS calendarDate
      FROM Calendar
      GROUP BY calendarYear, calendarMonth) Calendar
CROSS JOIN Account
CROSS JOIN AssetClass
LEFT JOIN MarketData
       ON MarketData.account = Account.account
          AND MarketData.assetClassCode = AssetClass.assetClassCode
          AND MarketData.marketDate = Calendar.calendarDate 
JOIN (SELECT account, marketValue,
             marketDate AS valueStartDate,
             LEAD(marketDate, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, marketDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY account, assetClassCode ORDER BY marketDate) AS valueEndDate
      FROM MarketData) MarketValue
  ON MarketValue.Account = Account.account
     AND MarketValue.assetClassCode = AssetClass.assetClassCode
     AND Calendar.calendarDate >= MarketValue.valueStartDate
     AND Calendar.calendarDate < MarketValue.valueEndDate
ORDER BY Account.account, Calendar.calendarDate, AssetClass.assetClassCode
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63dc4/3/0)</kbd>

(Note that I've adjusted the ordering of the conditions in the `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, to better reflect the "primary" keys used: account and asset class code)

Comment: I really appreciate all the time you spent explaining and doing this. It appears to work well. I will study it a bit more to make sure. The one thing I'm not sure of is if this is adding dates before or after the actual date range. I need to fill in the gaps only within the min and max dates of the original table not before or after.

Comment: @JayC - updated query to limit to last entry.  It was already limited to the earliest entry (given the join condition required for the lower-bound), I just assumed the value would continue into the future.

Comment: What are you doing with COALESCE in the first few rows? I know Coalesce pulls the first non null value but what is the use of it here? In your GROUP BY it seems like you are aliasing the group by as Calendar and the CROSS join as account? I've never done this how does it work? Lastly why are you using CROSS JOIN and what it is it doing? Here is the SQL. Lastly how do I insert code in the comment section in StackOverflow? CTRL+K doesn't work.       GROUP BY calendarYear, calendarMonth) Calendar
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT account
            FROM NetxTWR) Account

Comment: BTW the SQL above is after I changed the code to match my tables. The SQL Code you have in this post didn't work, but the code you have in your SQL Fiddle does. One other question. Why are you using MAX() to get the start date? Why not MIN?

Comment: @jayC - Because without `COALESCE`, those columns would report **null**, and not the "instant" value of `0`.  `CROSS JOIN` multiplies all rows together - if table1 has 2 rows and table2 has 3 rows, you get 6 rows, one with each possible combination.  It's the equivalent of `JOIN ... ON 1 = 1` (always true).  It's how to guarantee I always have a base row (account and date).  I'm using `MAX(..)` because I need the **LAST** day of the month, which is what your entries were keyed to.  `MIN(..)` would give me the first, which wouldn't work.  Use backticks (```) to denote code in comments/etc.

Comment: I added a second but closely related follow up question. The logic you provided works great on single attribute tables, but some tables have multiple criteria and need to have sub partitioning to accomplish the result. If you have a moment please look at the update. Is it possible to adjust the existing query to accommodate this? I tried but couldn't get the right result, particularly the need to pull the last market value specific to asset classes.

Comment: I tried the query but I am getting quadruple values for all rows. Not sure why yet. I included my query and sample output.

Comment: The only way to get more rows is to 1] have extra rows to begin with (not just 1), and 2] not restrict the rows based on a condition.  Check your base data - is it possible you have two matching rows in `FTPerfCACCAssetClass` (multiplied from each join)?  Although that should also have appeared with my original query.  Alternatively, you may have too many rows in the `CACC_Codes` table, but it's unlikely you added four of the same value...

Comment: The values are unique. This wasn't happening because I wasn't joining the CAC_Codes table before. I have seen this before qhere values quadruple. I need to research it.

Comment: Here is another thread where the values were quadrupling in a similar manner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881918/sql-partition-data-within-and-outside-of-a-common-table-expression

Comment: You were right some of those values were quadrupled in the original data source. Thank you again for all the hlep.

Answer (score 0):

You need a date or numbers table to fill in the gaps.  I had a similar problem a while back.  Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86435/filling-in-date-holes-in-grouped-by-date-sql-data.

In your case, after selecting from the numbers/calendar table, you'll have to do a subquery in an ISNULL to get the most recent value.  This can be very expensive.  Something like this...

```
SELECT ...
ISNULL(t.TWR, 0) TWR, 
ISNULL(t.MarketValue, (SELECT MarketValue FROM Table inner WHERE inner.Date <= t.Date ORDER BY t.Date DESC) MarketValue
FROM Calendar c WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Table t ON t.Date=c.Date
WHERE c.Date >= @StartDate AND c.Date < @EndDate
```

Comment: It would _help_, certainly, but isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: This gets me close but I can't get it to work with my data http://tomaslind.net/2015/07/07/how-to-fill-in-gaps-in-time-series/

Comment: @JayC: See update.  If there's a way to do it without a subquery I'd love to see it too, as I have very similar data and SQL is not very good with this type of query.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: true.  If it's something simple where performance isn't the greatest concern, the table-valued function I documented in my question is the fastest way I've found to get the data on the fly.  A CTE expression with the same basic function could also be used, though it makes the resulting query much less readable.

Comment: I'm not able to join the calendar table with the original table. I made the calendar table so it has all the same rows as the original but with 0's for all values every account and every date. However I only want to join where the calendar table has a date that the original table is missing and the calendar table's date for a given account is within the min and max of a given account.

Comment: @JayC, it sounds like you're thinking about it backwards--you want to select the calendar table as the primary table and join the data to that.  The calendar table only needs calendar information in it, not any other kind of data.

Comment: Especially with SQL Server, [please don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Granted, we're likely dealing with actual `Date`s here, so the damage is limited, but always assume a measure can become more accurate at any time.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: thanks, nice article. Aaron is awesome!